# DefineCustomFiles and CustomCollectFiles are not fired by TeamCity

Tags: deployment, msbuild, continuous-integration, teamcity, publish

I'm trying to publish extra files with TeamCity. I also opened a subject here: [Publish extra dll files not included in the web project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969883/publish-extra-dll-files-not-included-in-the-web-project) but here I'm focused on the fact that DefineCustomFiles and CustomCollectFiles seem not fired.

My build step looks like this:

[image: TeamCity build step]

And my custom build file looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This file is used by the publish/package process of your Web project. You can customize the behavior of this process
by editing this MSBuild file. In order to learn more about this please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
        <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
            DefineCustomFiles;
            CustomCollectFiles;
            $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
        </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="BuildAll" DependsOnTargets="Compile">
        <Message Text="=== BuildAll ===" Importance="high" />
    </Target>
    <Target Name="Compile">
        <Message Text="=== Compile ===" Importance="high" />
        <MSBuild Projects="$(SolutionFile)" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)" />
    </Target>
    <Target Name="DefineCustomFiles">
        <Message Text="=== DefineCustomFiles ===" Importance="high" />
        <ItemGroup>
            <CustomFilesToInclude Include="example01.txt" />
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>
    <Target Name="CustomCollectFiles">
        <Message Text="=== CustomCollectFiles ===" Importance="high" />
        <ItemGroup>
            <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="@(CustomFilesToInclude)">
                <DestinationRelativePath>%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
            </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

The example01.txt file is at the root of my project, like my custom build file.

Problems:

- I can't see the DefineCustomFiles and CustomCollectFiles targets fired in TeamCity's log
- My example file is not added during the publication

Thanks for any help!

**UPDATE**

The problem comes from the separate file! Now I use the standard .csproj file with this at the end:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
        CustomCollectFiles;
        $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="CustomCollectFiles">
    <Message Text="=== CustomCollectFiles ===" Importance="high" />
    <ItemGroup>
        <_CustomFiles Include="..\Extra Files\**\*" />
        <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
            <DestinationRelativePath>%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
        </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

And it works, oh yeah!!

**UPDATE**

And my build step in Team City is finally:

[image]

Comment: Why are you having a custom buildall target in a separate file is my question. Isn't it just fine to call the build or rebuild target of your project and hooking in your targets like you have done with DependsOn? Does it work locally and not in TeamCity?

Comment: It's better to replace all /p: parameters with System properties in Parameters tab.

Comment: DefineCustomFiles is not called

Comment: You are right Johan, the problem comes from the separate file, I update the post to insert the right modifications. Thanks A LOT!

Comment: Hi Leo - with your update, did you have to specify the CustomCollectFiles target in teamcity? Also, it looks like you didnt need the other targets i.e. Buildall etc - is that the case? I am pulling my hair out with this too!

Comment: No, I didn't specify this target in TeamCity. I just updated the answer with the command line parameters I have, I hope this will help.